# Self referencing schema for versioning

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to version documents in a collection, such that any changes to a document make a copy, and save the edited copy as 'current' and the previous version is preserved, along with time stamps, person editing, etc.  I have designed a schema like:

```
var doc = new Schema;
doc.Add({ created: Date, 
          created_by:{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
          doc_id: String, 
          doc_data: String, 
          prev_docs:[doc]
});
```

So editing a doc would take the current doc, make a copy, and update the document, sticking current_doc into prev_docs, etc.

1. Can a schema reference itself, like `prev_docs` does?
2. Is this design pattern scalable in MongoDB? `prev_docs` would only ever be used as an audit trail, users would not generally see previous versions, and the would be excluded completely from most queries.

Comment: 1) that isn't valid JavaScript syntax, `doc` would be `undefined.` You'd need to use Schema.add: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add. 2) I wouldn't store the audit information in the same collection if it wasn't used frequently.

Comment: The code is pseudo javascript, I don't actually have it implemented